# Configure homestead for subdomain routing

Tags: php, laravel-5, homestead

Please how do I configure and use **dynamic** subdomain routing working on homestead.
I have set subdomain routing in routes.php

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{school}.myapp.com'], function () {
Route::get('/', 'HomepageController@enterSchool');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you update the `/etc/hosts` to add the sub-domains.

***Homestead.yaml***

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 8192
cpus: 1

folders:
    - map: path/to/application/repository_name_one
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/repository_name_one
sites:
    - map: repository_name_one.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/repository_name_one/public
    - map: subdomain.repository_name_one.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/repository_name_one/public
```

***/etc/hosts***

```
192.168.10.10   myapp.com
192.168.10.10   school.myapp.com
```

Answer (score 1):

> Create the dynamic subdomain using Laravel Homestead

For local development keep domain extension as ".test"

**If you are using Laravel Homestead :**

Create a site name in homestead.yml as **myapp.test**

```
sites: 
    -map: myapp.test
     to: /home/vagrant/myapp/public
     wildcard: "yes"
```

login to your homestead using "vagrant ssh" then edit nginx server_name to *.myapp.test

```
sudo vi /etc/nginx/sites-available/myapp.test
```

Now exit from homestead, do below mentioned steps on you local machine. Edit hosts file i.e /etc/hosts

```
sudo vi /etc/hosts    
192.168.10.10   *.myapp.test
```

Now edit dnsmasq file as below:

```
sudo vi /usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf
```

mention this in dnsmasq.conf file:

```
address=/test/192.168.10.10
```

Restart dnsmasq service:

```
[For Ubuntu users]
sudo /etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart 
[For Mac users]
sudo launchctl stop homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq 
sudo launchctl start homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq
```

Create a test file in directory "/etc/resolver/" as below:

```
sudo vi /etc/resolver/test
nameserver 127.0.0.1 #mention this code in test file
```

Thats it !!! Done !!!
Now, you can access any of subdomain such as:

```
abc.myapp.test
xyz.myapp.test
dynamicSubdomain.myapp.test
myapp.test
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it.

---

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 8192
cpus: 1

folders:
    - map: path/to/application/repository_name_one
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/repository_name_one
sites:
    - map: repository_name_one.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/repository_name_one/public
    - map: subdomain.repository_name_one.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/repository_name_one/public
```

```php
Route::group(
    [
        'domain' => 'subdomain.repository_name_one.dev'
    ],
    function () {

        [...]

    }
);
```

Comment: Still getting webpage not available. Do I need to restart homestead?

Comment: Actually am trying to implement a dynamic sub domain routing.

Comment: Yes. You need to provision the machine to load the new configuration.

Comment: hope my database wont be lost after provision? Kinda new to laravel and homestead

Comment: Just to make sure you should make a backup before provisioning.

Comment: webpage not available after I provision homestead